# Как подключить woocommerce на WordPress платежным системам по РФ

Tags: wordpress

Коллеги, приветствую. 
Подскажите, есть ли возможность подключить интернет магазин на вордпресс woocommerce к платежным системам для онлайн оплаты с сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Для эгото можно испольовать такие системы как Robokassa- https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/robokassa или interkassa

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.